# How can I setup the NuGet configuration to work under the IIS App Pool user account so I can download files from a custom NuGet source in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, nuget

I am trying to download NuGet packages from a custom nuget server using an ASP.NET MVC website. The code I have runs fine under a console app, but when I run it under IIS I receive an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Package stream for 'MyPackage.1.0.0' cannot be found at 'https://mynugetserverurl'.

Each run under different credentials. My local user in the case of the console app and the standard IIS User (APP POOL\my.domain.name.com) in the other.

My custom nuget package source is setup for my local user and I have tried setting up the nuget.config for the IIS user in many different locations per this nuget documentation (https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file), but none appear to be recognized.

How can I setup the NuGet configuration to work under the IIS App Pool user account so I can download files from a custom NuGet source in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Are you downloading NuGet packages programmatically? If you want download should happen in context of current user then check impersonation option.

Comment: Yes, I'm downloading programmatically using NuGet.Core package and no I'm not impersonating anybody presently. Is impersonation required? Isn't there a way to give the correct configuration to NuGet by giving it a configuration file that the IIS user has access to (something in web root for example).

Comment: The exception I'm seeing is coming from line 145 of this code: https://github.com/NuGetArchive/NuGet.PackageManagement/blob/e294559ce47eeba9e7ec6df56743f8abad9ff7ca/src/PackageManagement/PackageDownloader.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out accessing nuget.config wasn't the issue after all. I found a version of the API where I could explicitly tell it which nuget.config file to use and verified that that user could access the file, but nothing changed. I confirmed that nuget was able to read the settings, but still the download wasn't working.

Tracing through the code I found out that DownloadToMachineCache (https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/fb6430c6f8c79ec7a28fc2e64e80b89ccb9b1e8b/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol.Core.v2/Resources/DownloadResourceV2.cs) was returning null. Code never reached line 301 because MachineCache.InvokeOnPackage was returning false. InvokeOnPackage calls a private method TryAct which reads as follows (https://github.com/ctaggart/nuget/blob/master/src/Core/Repositories/MachineCache.cs):

```
  try
  {
        // Do stuff...
        return action();
        // Do more stuff...
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  {
  }
  return false;
```

Arghh - how frustrating.... It doesn't properly handle the issue at any level to let a user know what happened! Instead it swallows any useful information here and covers up what's really going on. I won't complain about swallowing an exception if you gracefully recover or tell me how to fix it, but if you don't then please just let me have the info so I can figure it out myself!

Anyway - action() calls back the delegate in InvokeOnPackage which tries to create a file at **packagePath** and write the downloaded .nupkg there - finally!

packagePath resolves to: **C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache**

***Besides access to nuget.config, you also need write access to this path in order for NuGet to function under an IIS User.*** Hopefully I can find another NuGet API that will allow me to tell it to use a more appropriate path for it's on-disk cache!

**Note:** In my research I also came across this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2140

Maybe they'll be good enough to break me in upcoming release! I am currently using v3.3.

Hope someone finds this helpful.